# Laravel Passport 404

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.4, laravel-passport

I installed Laravel Passport using the Laravel docs, the Laravel version is 5.4.

Everything worked fine so far now I add these lines into my view:

```
      <!-- let people make clients -->
      <passport-clients></passport-clients>

      <!-- list of clients people have authorized to access our account -->
      <passport-authorized-clients></passport-authorized-clients>

      <!-- make it simple to generate a token right in the UI to play with -->
      <passport-personal-access-tokens></passport-personal-access-tokens>
```

The Ui looks good, but if I try to add a new Client or Token I get this message:

> Whoops! Something went wrong!
>
> ```
> Something went wrong. Please try again.
> ```

And my Chrome dev console shows me following:

```
GET http://192.168.3.80/oauth/tokens 404 (Not Found) app.js:1175
GET http://192.168.3.80/oauth/personal-access-tokens 404 (Not Found) app.js:1175
GET http://192.168.3.80/oauth/scopes 404 (Not Found) app.js:1175
```

I followed the steps writing in the docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/passport

Afterwards I followed the steps at the video which are the same but it still does not work. https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-3/episodes/13

If I press on a button I get this post error in the dev console:

POST http://localhost/oauth/clients 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost/oauth/clients 404 (Not Found)
POST http://localhost/oauth/clients 404 (Not Found)

So it is due to the path?

The vue file shows this:

Clients.vue

```
        store() {
            this.persistClient(
                'post', '/oauth/clients',
                this.createForm, '#modal-create-client'
            );
        },
```

Comment: Set `APP_DEBUG=true` in your `.env` file, so you can see the detailed error.

Comment: It's set true where can I see the detailed one?

Comment: Then you should see a detailed log after the `Whoops! Something went wrong!`.

Comment: What does `artisan route:list` print?

Comment: You should have `Passport::routes();` at the end of the `boot()` method in your `AuthServiceProvider`. Did you checked that?

Comment: @GerardReches `Whoops! Something went wrong!` is an bootstrap alert message. . I do have `Passport::routes();` at the end of boot()

Comment: @tkausl `artisan route:list` prints following https://kopy.io/01GG5

Comment: Your `route:list` looks ok, debug isn't showing useful information and if you can see the components UI it means that they are compiled. I suppose that you have already ran the passport migrations.

Comment: @GerardReches yep I ran the php artisan make:auth first, so shall I reset all the migrations?

Comment: Nope, I mean `php artisan migrate`

Comment: @GerardReches ye I ran it nothing more to migrate, using Php 5.6 if that makes a difference

Comment: @GerardReches Thanks alot so far :) do you have any other guess?

Comment: No more ideas :( I only used Passport in one project, and I didn't used the components because I didn't need the admin panel.

Comment: @GerardReches ok thanks alot :) have a good week

Answer (score 1):

Side-channel communication (IRC) showed that Laravel was installed in a subpath (`http://192.168.3.80/myapp/public/`), and the urls assume that the application is in the root.

The solution is to change your webserver configuration and set the root (nginx) or DocumentRoot (apache) to Laravel's public folder.

Comment: How to change the configuration, and what lines to change?

Comment: This is basically what he means. I trust that you will be deploying your site to a virtual private server where you will have virtual hosts. That said, if you point your virtual host to the laravel public folder, the site will use this as root and this will work beautifully. No need to change the urls and what not.

If you are deploying to FTP hosting then you will have more pain than the above(which I do not know how to resolve).

So if you are deploying to a VPS, to enable local development, always use `php artisan serve` which will run the site from public and the urls will work.

Answer (score 0):

add .. before the url "/oauth/personal-access-tokens" as "../oauth/personal-access-tokens"
and do same for other urls also
it will work on laravel 5.8