# Laravel Passport not working when upload inside sub-folder

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel passport view,add,update,destroy not working when its uploade inside a sub-folder like: my-site.com/xyz

but if i upload it root directory , its working fine. 
I have change my app_url inside .env file.
Try out change the passport.php file router function with `prefix => 'xyz/oauth'`  and path inside client.vue file but nothings working. **I need to change the base url for passport**. Or any other solution.... 
i have also try `window.axios.defaults.baseURL='http://my-site.com/xyz';` and many others way but nothings working.

Help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using IIS. I had to bind my server root to my laravel public folder. The below answers helped me:

[Laravel Passport 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43471526/laravel-passport-404)